# How get multiplication result from generated text fields using Jquery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have generated textfields, i want the values textfield1 and textfield2 to be calculated by multiplying and get the result on textfield3.

for example:
I generate 4 textfields:

`textfield1 * textfields2 = txtfield3`
`textfield1 * textfield2 = txtfield3` 
`textfield1 * textfield2 = txtfield3`
`textfield1 * textfield2 = txtfield3`
`textfield1 * textfield2 = txtfield3`

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djy0v.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

First call elements using ID:

Use `parseInt` function to convert string to integer then multiply and attach value to `textfield3`:

It is easy like:

```
textfield1 = document.getElementById("textfield1");
textfield2 = document.getElementById("textfield2");
textfield3 = document.getElementById("textfield3");

textfield3.value = parseInt(textfield1.value) * parseInt(textfield2.value);
```